# How to get Bitcoin input transaction hash string from bitcoinjslib Transaction object?

Tags: bitcoinjs

I'm using bitcoinjs-lib and its Transaction object. Transaction.ins is an array of objects, each which has a hash and script property. Both of these properties are Uint8Arrays.

I am trying to get the hex string version of the input.hash but Transaction.ins[i].hash.toString('hex') produces an incorrect result. Is there a way to get this value properly?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to reverse the array before toString. `Transaction.ins[i].hash.reverse().toString('hex')` produces the correct result. Make sure to call hash.reverse() afterward.

source: [ScriptHash from bitcoin address with BitcoinJS](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68565/scripthash-from-bitcoin-address-with-bitcoinjs)